# SSRS Pie Chart - Get Label Lines to Point Inside the Chart

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, report-designer

Is it possible to have the label pointer lines to point within the pie chart area? I found that you can control the line size and bend with the Custom Attributes, "LabelsHorizontalLineSize" and "LabelsRadialLineSize" on the Chart Series, but can they point inside instead of outside?

Basically, I currently have a chart that looks like this:

[image: Original Chart]

but I would like it to look like this (with the dots at the end if possible):

[image: New Chart]

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio SSRS Report Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. This is one of the (many) limitations of SSRS

Comment: Just curious, but is there a long answer?

Comment: Not really, but there is a good article here to add some jazz to your pie charts https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3586/sql-server-reporting-services-multilayer-pie-charts/